# Parity - Syncing Very Slow Around Block 4.700.000 and overload disk

Tags: ether, parity

> I'm running:
>
> - **Which Parity version**: v1.10.7-stable-ba79cad-20180619/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.26.2
> - **Which operating system** Linux: Centos 7
> - **installed**: from source

My parity config

> db_compaction = "ssd"
>
> pruning = "archive"
>
> fat_db = "off"
>
> cache_size = 4096

Computer uptime more than 5 days, and i get: **4.731.002** blocks and disk is: **452G/500Gb SDD**
now, syncing very slow and disk is full. Where did I go wrong? eth blocks occupy more drive space.
When disk full 500Gb, what should I do?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `pruning` to either `"fast"` or `"light"`:

- `"fast"` will potentially save a lot of storage space and also run faster
- `"light"` will potentially save even more storage space

Comment: Thanks, after changed to "light", do i need delete old database? 
- and when i ran rpc: eth_getTransactionByHash, i get result is null.

Comment: Maybe you need to wait a little bit until it's synced...